# F# class hierarchy comparison

Tags: f#

What is the best way to tackle this problem?
Here is a simple class hierarchy in F#:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type BaseClass (name: string) = 
  member this.Name with get() = name

type FooClass (n, i: int) =
  inherit BaseClass (n)
  member this.Num with get() = i

type BarClass (n) = inherit BaseClass (n)
```

I will need to add to this hierarchy quite a lot as the project advances.
I need to equate instances of these classes by checking if they are the same type and have the same value for `Name` (and also the same value for `Num` if its a `FooClass`), so ReferenceEquals won't cut it. What is the best way to do this? Should I make `BaseClass` inherit IComparable and if so, how should I then deal with the types that inherit from `BaseClass` and have extra fields to check? Another way of doing it would be to make an IComparer class that checks for every different class but I really want the code to be in the appropriate class rather than in a comparer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe overriding equals on the base class, and then overriding equals on each sub class by leveraging the base class implementation is the standard approach in .NET OO:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type BaseClass (name: string) = 
  member this.Name with get() = name
  override this.Equals(other:obj) =
    match other with
    | :? BaseClass as other ->
        other.Name = this.Name
    | _ -> false


type FooClass (n, i: int) =
  inherit BaseClass (n)
  member this.Num with get() = i
  override this.Equals(other:obj) =
    match other with
    | :? FooClass as other when base.Equals(other) -> //check type equality with this, and base equality
        other.Num = this.Num //check the additional properties for this supertype
    | _ -> false

type BarClass (n, i: bool) =
  inherit BaseClass (n)
  member this.Truth with get() = i
    override this.Equals(other:obj) =
    match other with
    | :? BarClass as other when base.Equals(other) ->
        other.Truth = this.Truth
    | _ -> false

let f1 = FooClass("Foo", 1)
let f2 = FooClass("Foo", 1)
f1 = f2 //true
let f3 = FooClass("Foo", 2)
f1 = f3 //false

//polymorphism in action (bc1 BaseClass will use sub class override)
let checkBaseClassesForEquality (bc1:BaseClass) (bc2:BaseClass) =
    bc1 = bc2

checkBaseClassesForEquality f1 f2 //true
checkBaseClassesForEquality f1 f3 //false
```